# Web.xml for glassfish application is mandated or not

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am able to configuration of url pattern through `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/SimpleServlet"})` and all the HTTP request response works fine. I want to see the xml for this servlet, I tried searching in the project folder but I din't find any. Is it possible that the configuration could be done without creation of web.xml file, if not where can I find that file. Please help me understanding this.
Here I am using NetBeans IDE for the development.

Thanks in advance.!! :-)

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Yes it is possible to run your servlet container without using `Web.xml` file. Is it your answer?

Comment: Yes. But can we create one.??

Comment: definitely you can create. If you are using Netbeans then you should create new file -> `Standard Deployment Descriptor` found in `web` section. this way netbeans will do necessary work for you.